Job offer from a grant decider - what should I do?
I found myself in a very peculiar situation. As of recently, another department (different university) approached me. This department is well known in my country. I worked with them in the past and we published a couple of papers together.
It happens that the head of this department is a big shot in my field. He is also the head of the committee of a private foundation which funded me and my research in the past.
Said department is expanding and they expressed large interest in recruiting me. This would mean moving to another city (about 700 kilometers away) which I cannot at this moment for private reasons. Now the issue:
I guess they expect a decision soon. Meanwhile, I applied for a grant with that private foundation. I know that the head of said department will make the ultimate decision of whether my application is funded or not. What should I do? If I decline the offer now, I will diminish my funding chances. On the other hand, it feels not right to show interest in the offered position (since I cannot move there at this stage). Any insights appreciated.

If the foundation has proper ethics processes, this kind of conflict of interest ought to disqualify the department head from being involved in reviewing your application. And you probably should have disclosed the conflict when you applied.

It would be unethical for them to make a grant funding decision based on such other reasons. Most people are ethical and their reputation depends on ethical behavior (most cases).
If you would be interested in joining that department at a later time, you can say so but that it is impossible at the moment. Even if you aren't interested, you could say the same, thanking them for thinking about you.
In fact, accepting an offer and then being funded, with the decision on funding based on your acceptance, would also be unethical.
And if they make decisions on invalid grounds you probably shouldn't join them in any case.
